# How to hide URL link in Google Plus Sharing?

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to share the images from the server via Google Plus in Android platform. I have used the below code :

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
      .setType("text/plain")
      .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
      .getIntent();
```

It works fine, but I don't want to show URL link in the post.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the domain of a shared is not supported by the Google+ Platform. If it's a feature you'd like to see implemented you can [open a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry).